# Resource Hierarchy and Networking for a Google Cloud Organization with a single developer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

I have several projects in GCP which are publically accessible and will become commercial services. Since I found myself with many projects, I thought that I would try out the Google Cloud organization feature. However, I cannot complete the creation due to odd requirements.

Google puts forward a "Checklist" to set up Google Cloud for the organization. If I go under IAM & Admin -> Identity & Organization, the only option there is to go to the checklist to complete it. However, the checklist includes mandatory steps like creating VPCs and a certain Resource hierarchy, which are things that I don't need/want. I am the only developer and don't want to pay more for services that I don't use. I cannot remove these options. As such, the organization seems to be "unconfigured" from the point of view of Google.

At the same time, I'm wondering if it really changes anything and if there is any benefit for me to use an organization.

Edit: I am not following any documentation *per se*, as there is a quite detailed interactive "tutorial" which takes you through all the configuration steps directly on GCP. The problem is precisely that I cannot chose an option not in the tutorial for some steps. To give you an idea, see [this blog post, specifically Step 5.](https://www.chrisfarris.com/post/gcp-create-domain/)

Comment: are you following a documentation?, could you edit your post and provide the documentation that you are following.

Comment: so you are stuck in Step 5 - Start setting up GCP is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I asked the question because the networking and resource hierarchy that the tutorial forced me to create seemed way overkill for me. I continued to read about it and I think I understand better their use. I assume that I can simplify the configuration at a later stage? I would like to have an organization with little to no additional cost for now, which seemed incompatible with the structure created in the tutorial.

Comment: If you want to create an organization on your Google Cloud, you can read this guide on [Creating and managing organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) yes, you can later create the networking part like for the VPC if you need it, as your main concern is creating an organization on Google Cloud.